# CakePHP: How to view details from a foreign table?

Tags: cakephp

I have two models: member & vocation. They are structured this way:

```
MEMBER
member_id
last_name
first_name
vocation_id (foreign key)

VOCATION
vocation_id
description
```

In the view page of the member, I want to show the last name, first name and the description of its vocation. I couldn't seem to find it in the documentation.

I tried the basic CakePHP viewing but it returns just the ID of the vocation. I'm guessing I need to make a new function in my MembersController to find the vocation details he has. I just need the standard on how to do it. I will look more in the documentation. Perhaps I just missed something there. I'll just update this question if I find the answer. For now, here's my current code:

```
<h1>#<?php echo h($member['Member']['member_id']); ?></h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><?php echo $member['Member']['last_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><?php echo $member['Member']['first_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Vocation</td>
        <td><?php echo $member['Member']['vocation_id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What is your specific problem?  Asked in the current way, it sounds like you want someone to write your code for you, which is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: @Dave I edited my question to add what I have tried so far. Thanks for the constructive comment.

Comment: As a general hint for such issues, you can use `var_dump($member)` in your view to see its keys. @AceEusebio

Comment: Noted. Will definitely use that in the future. I'll look up on what var_dump does exactly. Thanks @sємsєм!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <td>Vocation</td>
    <td><?php echo $member['Vocation']['vocation_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Vocation description</td>
    <td><?php echo $member['Vocation']['description']; ?></td>
</tr>
```